# Synchronize multiple android devices with SQL server via rest

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

I have an android app used for inserting a simple data on the server via REST/Volley/JSON. Simple design. You open the app, read the data from server via one Rest request. And you can insert any new data which are send to server immediately when internet connection is available. But I need to make it work on multiple devices. So if Insert some data via device A into the server, device B needs to be informed that it is necessary to reload data from server, or new data have to be send directly to device B. Is there any ease way that server can send info to all devices that reload has to be done? I do not need to do any handling of colisions as there is only insert no update od DB.

Easiest solution is to check each ~60 seconds for new data from each app. 
**But I need better solution when synchronization is triggered by server.**
For example each device registers its IP address on server and server sends some kind of special PING to all registered devices, which can be checked by the app ? Or it send directly new data in JSON..

Or to use some third party service just for this synchronization ?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest GCM as a trick. When device A access insert.php, if the data is successfully inserted , send a push a notification to devices b and c.

In GCM onMessage arrival code- call server and update the data in devices.

If you devices checks every 60secs, It may drain battery like anything. And no user will like it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure cloud for that real time synchrnization. Azure's SDK will keep tables synced to the server.